# How to delete an item on click from dynamically generated content javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a very basic task application with vanilla javascript. I have an array and from that, I am rendering the todos dynamically. I want to delete a todo when the checkbox is clicked.

I tried to create a form with the id of the todo in the hidden input and on change event submit the form and delete the todo but I'm generating all of them dynamically. Don't you think it will be a lot of code?

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you

```js
const todos = ['Complete the todo app', 'Write a script', 'Record a video', 'Publish the video']

const renderTodos = function (todos) {

    document.querySelector('#todos').innerHTML = ''
    
    todos.forEach(function (todo, index) {

        const divElem = document.createElement('div')
        divElem.classList.add(`item`, `item-${index}`)
        document.querySelector('#todos').appendChild(divElem)

        const checkboxElem = document.createElement('input')
        checkboxElem.type = 'checkbox'
        checkboxElem.name = 'deleteTodo'
        document.querySelector(`.item-${index}`).appendChild(checkboxElem)

        const titleElem = document.createElement('p')
        titleElem.textContent = todo
        document.querySelector(`.item-${index}`).appendChild(titleElem)

    })
}

renderTodos(todos)

document.querySelector('#add-todo').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (e.target.elements.newItem.value === '') {
        return
    }
    todos.push(e.target.elements.newItem.value)
    e.target.elements.newItem.value = ''
    renderTodos(todos)
})
```

```html
<div id="todos"></div>

<form class="item" id="add-todo" action="">
  <input
    type="text"
    name="newItem"
    placeholder="New Item"
    autocomplete="off"
  />
  <button type="submit" name="list">+</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want to delete just by selecting the checkbox?

Comment: Yes, delete the todo when the checkbox is clicked. I know how to remove that item. but I'm looking for a better way to get the id of that todo.

Comment: It is not interesting to be using "renderTodos" to add a new item, as it will go through all the previous ones and this is not interesting in terms of performance. Then create a new function to add a new item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use remove method :

```js
const DomParser = new DOMParser()
  ,   todoAll   = document.getElementById('todos')
  ,   todoForm  = document.getElementById('add-todo')
  ,   todos     = ['Complete the todo app', 'Write a script', 'Record a video', 'Publish the video']
  ;
function todoAdding(todo, index)
  {
  let elmZ = `<div class="item item-${index}"><input type="checkbox" name="deleteTodo"><p>${todo}</p></div>`;
  let inZ  = DomParser.parseFromString( elmZ, 'text/html');
  todoAll.appendChild( inZ.body.firstChild ) 
  }
function renderTodos(todos)
  {
  document.querySelector('#todos').innerHTML = ''
  todos.forEach( todoAdding )
  }
todoForm.onclick = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()
  if (todoForm.newItem.value === '') return
  todos.push(todoForm.newItem.value)
  todoForm.newItem.value = ''
  renderTodos(todos)
  }
todoAll.onclick = e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('input[type=checkbox]')) return
  let suppIndex = todos.findIndex(todo=>todo===e.target.parentNode.querySelector('p').textContent)
  todos.splice(suppIndex,1)
  e.target.parentNode.remove()
  }
renderTodos(todos)  // initial case
```

```html
<div id="todos"></div>

<form class="item" id="add-todo" action="">
  <input
    type="text"
    name="newItem"
    placeholder="New Item"
    autocomplete="off"
  />
  <button type="submit" name="list">+</button>
</form>
```